# How do I determine which ListView item, and it's Url, was selected when the user pins from the BottomAppBar

Tags: c#, windows-8, windows-runtime, listviewitem, winrt-async

I have a basic RSS reader that displays the list of Blog posts in a listView in the left Grid.Column. In the Right Grid.Column is the WebView. When the user selects an item in the listView, the Webview is updated with Uri and displays the web page.

Now, I've added a BottomAppBar and created Pin/UnPin buttons. I've successfully created the pinning ability, however, I am not passing any data into the NavigationContext's query string. So when the user clicks on the pinned tile, it only deeplinks to the overall page and not the selected article. This loads all the latest articles and not the selected item's url.

I know I have to pass the Url into the pinned tile's querystring, but I'm stuck here. I've done this dozens of time in my Windows Phone apps, but I'm stuck here for this Windows 8 app. On WP7, I am using a context menu to pin the item. Here I am pinning from the appbar and I can't seem to get the url and add it as a querystring (As my TileActivationArgument)

Mainly I need guidance with how to get the selected item's data and get it onto the tile and how to read it coming back in. Here is my Pin() method:

EDIT: I've gone ahead and made a temporary working solution, but it doesn't solve my issue of not being able to retrieve the selected item's properties. Comments are inline w/the code

```
private async void PinTileHelper(string message, object sender)
    {
        //This is my preferred method, but I cannot extract the SelectedItem's properties
        //var item = itemListView.SelectedItem;


        //I'm not able to use the sender because this is a button click
        //var selectedItem = (FeedItems)((ListView)sender).SelectedItem;

        //As a cheesy workaround, I just took the Uri directly from the WebView's source Uri
        var ActivationArgument = this.ContentView.Source.ToString();

        Uri logo = new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/squareTile-sdk.png");
        //Uri smallLogo = new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/smallTile-sdk.png");

        SecondaryTile secondaryTile = new SecondaryTile("Toolbox",
                                                        "Fantasy Football Tile",
                                                        "Article name goes here and ",
                                                        ActivationArgument,
                                                        TileOptions.ShowNameOnLogo,
                                                        logo);

        secondaryTile.ForegroundText = ForegroundText.Dark;
        //secondaryTile.SmallLogo = smallLogo;

        bool isPinned = await secondaryTile.RequestCreateAsync();

        MessageDialog dialog = new MessageDialog("Pinned?");

        if (isPinned)
        {
            dialog.Content = "You have succesfully pinned this tile";
            await dialog.ShowAsync();
        }
        else
        {
            dialog.Content = "Something went wrong. The tile wasn't pinned.";
            await dialog.ShowAsync();
        }
    }
```

Thanks for any insight you can provide.

EDIT #2: Success!! Safe casting to your ItemViewModel items does the trick.

```
var item = itemListView.SelectedItem as FeedItems (or your ItemViewModel items);
```

Comment: Can you show the code that you are using for the pin and unpin now?  Getting a selected item from a listView is pretty straightforward (listView.selectedItem), so I am not sure I quite understand where the issue is.

Comment: I've added the code above. As you can see I'm still using the SDK default of DateTime for the TileArgument. What I need to to do is hold the selected ListView Item's Url. When the user navigates in from the tile, the WebView will display the URl. This is important because the RSS feed list will push posts down quickly. If the user can pin a specific page then it makes pinning a desired UX

Comment: It also appears that I have to grab the LaunchArgs in App.xaml.cs, then pass it to SplitPage.xaml (which is where the tile deeplinks to). Or does WinRT automatically send it to the deeplinked page and I can grab the TileArgument directly from OnNavigatedTo e.Parameter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try replacing

```
var selectedItem = (FeedItems)((ListView)sender).SelectedItem;
```

with

```
var selectedItem = (FeedItems)((ListView)sender).SelectedItem as FeedItem;
```

I'm assuming that is the correct class Type for the as statement. This will let you access all of the properties, including Uri, on the selected item.  If selectedItem is null after this call, you are not casting to the right Type.  Cast to the appropriate class type.  Right now, with the code as is, you are getting a plain old object back.

Yes, you grab the LaunchArgs and pass them on to your destination page as part of handling your start navigation.

Comment: The safe cast did the trick as far as getting the objects from my class, but now I get the error because the sender is a button not the list view. Am I going to have to do this as context menu?

Comment: Ha! Using your idea, I did a safe cast on my first attempt and it worked. So the solution is "var item = itemListView.SelectedItem as FeedItems". I will update my question. Thanks for the help!